# Similarity between two time series

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, accelerometer, similarity

I have two files with accelerator readings and I want to get some metric/ measurement to get the similarity between these two files.
I have tried Pearson’s R coefficient, dtw distance, dtw score.
Pearson’s r gives returns a value 1 if the files are identical, the dtw score and path are 0 if the files are identical.

But I need a solution if the files are as the ones in the figures, similar, with a little time lag. They are readings from two different accelerators who were attached to the same source. The sampling frequency and amplitude is not same. Even the number of readings are not same. Time stamps could be different.

How do I measure the similarity between such files? Is there some metric or measurement I can get using Python? Because dtw score and dtw distance do give some output, but there is no way I can say the files are similar using those values.

[image: File 1]

[image: File 2]

Comment: This is everything but trivial. Before being able to measure the similarity, you first have to make the inputs have the same characteristics (like amplitude, sample rate, number of channels). This step alone depends heavily on your intended purpose. Even if I assume the easiest possible follow-up steps (frequency, phase and direction of vibration is not important) you still need to calculate an amplitude profile (choose between with or without gravity correction), possibly filter noise, and finally resample to a common sample rate.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus Thank you for your response. What steps and metrics do you suggest?? Could you suggest any python packages or libraries??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read them using pandas and get correlations after successive lags e.g. if you have them as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': range(10),
                   'val2': [0]*5 + list(range(5))})
df
  val1 val2
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5   0
6   6   1
7   7   2
8   8   3
9   9   4
```

You can do

```
max([df.val1.corr(df.val2.shift(-delay)) for delay in range(1, len(df))])
>>> 1.0
```

This will always result in `1.0` incase both are the same with some delays as it is getting correlation after each incorporating each delay. You can be creativewith the delay range as per your data to avoid looping through all of it or modify into a for loop with conditional `break` to stop right where you find out its actually sits at `1.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the problem is that the values in the columns are not the same. The amplitude is varying. You can see from the graphs, the values have a different range. Only their waveforms/patterns look the same. I want to be able to identify that the signals are coming from the same source (taken using different devices), with varying values and time lag.

Comment: For correlation absolute amplitude does not matter neither the scaling. E.g.  `df.val1.corr(df.val1*2+82)` will also produce 1.0 so it is also valid in this case. As soon as waveform are similar to one another, it will be `1.0`. Thats how correlation is calculated

Comment: I tried the above method. And the value of correlation came as ~0.7. Is there any other way to get the similarity?